# Simple Snake game function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to write a simple snake game for my final school project but i got stuck on my last function. I guess I don't really know how to use the datastructures perfectly. The funcition `doInstruction` should give back True for this testcase `doInstruction (Turn East) (North, [(5, 7), (5, 6)], 2) == (East, [(5, 7), (5, 6)], 2)` What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
data Dir = West
    | North
    | East
    | South deriving (Eq, Show)

type Position = (Int, Int)
type Snake = (Dir, [Position], Int)

data Instruction = Move | Turn Dir deriving (Eq, Show)

isOppositeDir :: Dir -> Dir -> Bool
isOppositeDir West East = True
isOppositeDir East West = True
isOppositeDir North South = True
isOppositeDir South North = True
isOppositeDir _ _ = False

oppositeDir :: Dir -> Dir
oppositeDir West = East
oppositeDir East = West
oppositeDir North = South
oppositeDir South = North

nextPos :: Dir -> Position -> Position
nextPos x (a,b)
    | x == West = (a - 1 , b)
    | x == East = (a + 1 , b)
    | x == North = (a , b + 1)
    | x == South = (a , b - 1)
    | otherwise = (a , b)

doInstruction :: Instruction -> Snake -> Snake
doInstruction ins s 
    | ins == Turn Dir = (oppositeDir Dir, [Position], length [Position])
```

The errors I get:

```
E:\\ELTE\2019_1_Funkcprog\hf13.hs:34:19: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Dir :: Dir
   |
34 |     | ins == Turn Dir = (oppositeDir Dir, [Position], length [Position])
   |                   ^^^

E:\\ELTE\2019_1_Funkcprog\hf13.hs:34:38: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Dir :: Dir
   |
34 |     | ins == Turn Dir = (oppositeDir Dir, [Position], length [Position])
   |                                      ^^^

E:\\ELTE\2019_1_Funkcprog\hf13.hs:34:44: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Position :: Position
   |
34 |     | ins == Turn Dir = (oppositeDir Dir, [Position], length [Position])
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^

E:\\ELTE\2019_1_Funkcprog\hf13.hs:34:63: error:
    Data constructor not in scope: Position
   |
34 |     | ins == Turn Dir = (oppositeDir Dir, [Position], length [Position])
   |                                                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: `Dir`, `Position`, etc. are not *values* (dat constructors), but types. Hence that does not make much sense.

Comment: Casing of names is crucial in Haskell. In particular all variables, including functions, must start with a lowercase letter - the only exception is constructor functions, which are defined as part of `data` (and `newtype`) declarations. Had you use `dir` instead of `Dir` here you would have been fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use *pattern matching* to "unpack" the data constructor. Variables in Haskell start with a *lowercase*. We thus can unpack the `Instruction` object, and the 3-tuple that represents the snake:

```
doInstruction :: Instruction -> Snake -> Snake
doInstruction (Turn dir) (_, p, l) = (dir, p, l)
```

Comment: Now it's working fine for the Turn instruction, but the Move not coming together. It looks like this : ```doInstruction (Move) (d, p, l) = (d, nextPos d p, l)``` and i got typerrors for [Poistion] and Position

Comment: @vNSkyline You have that `p` is a list-of-positions, but `nextPos` only expects one position. Also, `nextPos` only returns a single position, while you need a list-of-positions in the tuple. I'd recommend to write an auxiliary function `nextPosList ::  Dir -> [Position] -> [Position]` which can exploit your `nextPos`. You probaly need to "move" the snake, removing the last element from the list, and adding the new one in the front (or vice versa, depending on which side of the list is the "head" of the snake).

Comment: @chi That's sound good, but how can i iterate through the list of tuples and change their value, or remove them and insert new ones applied with the ```nextPos``` function?

Comment: @vNSkyline If I understood correctly, you don't need to change their values very much. You need to drop the last (`init` does that), and prepend the new one (`x:xs` prepends `x` to `xs`). Don't think of the snake as an array (where you would need to change each cell), but as a list (where you can append/prepend cells).